# Show that, for every real number a, the set {$x ∈ S | f(x) ≤ a$} is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that $S$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^d$ and that $f$ is a continuous real-valued function
with domain $S$. Show that, for every real number $a$, the set
{$x ∈ S | f(x) ≤ a$}
is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^d$

I don't know how to start this. Do we use the fact that
If $S$ is closed and bounded every sequence in $S$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $S$?

Comment: Choose an arbitrary converging sequnce in the set and show that its limit also lies in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that if $f$ is continuous function, for any close set $C$, $f^{-1}(C)$ is also close set. So $\{x ∈ S | f(x) ≤ a\}=f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is closed for $(-\infty,a]$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

A common definition of "continuous" is that the inverse images of open sets are open; the inverse images of their complements are thus closed.  I am assuming you are using a different definition based on limits as in Baby Rudin.

With that definition, and writing $T=\{x\in S:f(x)\le a\}$, we want to show that the limits of convergent sequences in $T$ also lie in $T$.  Consider such a sequence $x_n$.  The values $f(x_n)$ all satisfy $f(x_n)\le a$ and, on account of continuity, $f(\lim x_n)=\lim f(x_n)$.  Because $\{y:y\le a\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, we have $\lim f(x_n)\le a$, and so we have $\lim x_n\in T$ as desired.